# SSL handshake failed with c# and windows7

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

Im trying to make simple https request to my web server api.
The code Im using:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var uri = new Uri("https://example.com");
            var cli = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = uri };
            var s = cli.GetStringAsync("").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws an error:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Also same problem if using c++ and boost+openssl. I tried everything: enable TLS 1.2 in system, specify force usage with **ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol** but it doesnt help.
Networkmonitor says that version I send is 1.2 as I need.

[image]

With all other known https sites its work OK (e.g. google.com).
Hope someone can help me figure out what is going on.

Comment: *"With all other known https sites its work OK (e.g. google.com)"* - so the problem is really with example.com? Or it is really another website? Since the problem happens only with a specific site we need to know which it it in order to find out its specific requirements.

Comment: on windows10 it works without any problem

Comment: Windows10 has a different TLS stack than Windows7, i.e. different regarding supported ciphers etc. But again, debugging the problem requires knowledge of the specific website in order to find out its requirements.